# Is there a way to declare timeout period with NUnit?

Tags: .net, api, nunit

I would like to be able to fail the test if the executing code hangs.  Is there a way to do this currently?

I am thinking something like the following must exist, but I can't seem to find it in the API

```
[Test, Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))]
public void Test() { ...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [NUnit 2.5](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=download)?  A [TimeoutAttribute](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=timeout&r=2.5) was added in NUnit 2.5 that does exactly what you want, though you specify the timeout in milliseconds.  See the [release notes](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.5).

Comment: Didn't even know that a new one is out, upgrading is fun

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's nothing built into NUnit that'll do this but it should be easy enough to do with DateTime (or performance counters if you're wanting higher resolution timers)...

Comment: AFAIK == As Far As I Know?  Man we're getting silly with these internet acronyms.  Thanks though!